# Maven release use parts

Tags: java, maven, release

Maven release plugin is a cool tool which simplifies releasing. But I want to change the behavior a little bit.

Most important I do not want any changes to be commited to the repository automatically. This should be done by developers manually.

I am dreaming of something like:

1. checking that no SNAPSHOT dependency is used (must)
2. checking that there are no uncommited changes (optional)
3. updating version numbers of all artifacts, allow user to enter new version number (must)

   - solved: with with `mvn versions:set`
4. build project locally

   - solved: with `mvn clean install`

I do not know how to cherry-pick some of the methods which do the work in release-plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you not concerned about missing one of the major advantages of the release plugin - the assurance that the code committed to the repository is definitely the code that has been freshly checked out and built correctly? Nevertheless, do you think the `dryRun` settings on the plugin might help? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#dryRun

Comment: No I am not concerned because we are using a Continous Build Server. This server defines how to build. dry-run did not help, because maven "sends" a svn command (and svn is not installed on my machine), resulting in an svn unknown error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you described will be automatically be done by the maven-release-plugin. If you don't have svn installed on the build server you need to configure the release plugin to use the [svnkit installation](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/)

Comment: Yes, my ideas came from the things the plugin does. I am going to try to configure maven using svnkit. Maybe my question was a little bit confusing: I needed an idea how to use parts of the goal relase:prepare or does maven forces me to use the complete goal or nothing? (sorry i am not a maven-expert yet)

Comment: I agreed with khmarbaise, all 4 points you mentioned is covered by the default behaviour of maven-release-plugin without any extra configuration. for a release, we usually do `mvn release:prepare` first (which handle 1,2,3 and 4), then followed by `mvn release:perform`.

Comment: Do you also tag automatically? I do want to tag only if the release has been build successfully in the way it is defined on the buildServer. No tagging for developers.

Comment: @khmarbaise do you know a documentation how to use svnkit? Documentation on the site you provided is not easy to follow.

Comment: Okay using svnkit installations works. Finally we are using maven release plugin completly. No need for any customizing. :-)